# What is Zephyr Breeze's special talent according to his Cutie Mark?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

Typically, in the MLP universe, once a pony realizes their special talent, their Cutie Mark materializes and that pony spends their lives utilizing that skill, having realized that it was what they were meant to do.

In *Flutter Brutter* (S06E11), we meet Zephyr Breeze, who has his cutie mark, but seems to have no direction in his life.

### What skill or talent does Zephyr Breeze's Cutie Mark depict?

Comment: Looks like a rose to me....

Comment: And what skill does the rose represent?

Comment: Mane therapy? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I figured that the feather and wind represented the phrase "Go where the wind takes me"
Zephyr goes with the flow, can't seem to stay in one place for too long, etc.
I think that his cutie mark more represents who he is rather than what he's meant to do. Like Diamond Tiara- her talent has nothing to do with tiaras, or jewelry at all. Her talent is persuasion and getting what she wants. The tiara represents more of who she is: a rich "spoiled princess" character. Likewise, Zephyr's cutie mark refers less to his talent, but rather has to do with flexibility and his go with the flow personality.

But that's just me.

Answer (score 3):

### Mane therapy

Zephyr's cutie mark appears to be a feather and a wave.

[image: turquoise winged pony with blonde horse hair, standing on his back legs]

[image: close-up on the cutie mark, looking like a feather and wave]

His talent seems to lie in mane therapy:

> **Zephyr Breeze**: [singsong] Guess who graduated from mane therapy training?
>
> **Rainbow Dash:** Hah, awesome!
>
> **Mr. Shy**: Congratulations, son!
>
> **Mrs. Shy**: You look so handsome!
>
> **Fluttershy**: I'm so proud of you, Zephyr.
>
> **Zephyr Breeze**: It was only a matter of time before they recognized my
> true genius! **But actually doing the work probably helped**, and I
> wouldn't have if it weren't for you.

It would seem that Zephyr's problem was his inability to do the work necessary to complete mane therapy school, and once he doubled down he was able to complete it. That this is his status at the end of the episode supports that hypothesis.

The imagery of a wave suggests waves of hair, as in a pony's mane, and the feather seems to denote style. As such, it shows his talent as a mane therapist.

Comment: His cutie mark may have been designed to match his name: "noun: zephyr; 1. a soft gentle breeze"

Comment: @Ajedi32 - Good point. I think it could have two meanings, since all cutie marks are supposed to have some relation to a pony's destiny.

Comment: Another explanation could be it is meant to represent a feather carried by the wind. After all, in a way, he couldn't find his place and was like a feather going round and round in the storm, without a clear direction to follow in life other than going where the currents left him.